# Duplicate div in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created this PHP code in WordPress to add image to the menu, but it is duplicating a div where there is an add button and I don't know why, I need it to be only one and not two results of the div, in case I only want the left div... I'll add an image about what I'm talking about so you can analyze my problem!
Structure is placed inside function `wp_post_thumbnail_only_html`
I left only the action that passes the button to facilitate.

[image]

```js
<?php
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class SNAP_Menu_Image{



    public function __construct() {

    
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ), 99 );

    }

    public function admin_init() {
        if ( !has_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields' ) ) {
        }
        add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', array( $this, 'menu_item_custom_fields' ), 10, 4 );
    }

    public function file_is_displayable_image( $result, $path ) {
        if ( $result ) {
            return true;
        }
        $fileExtension = pathinfo( $path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        return in_array( $fileExtension, $this->additionalDisplayableImageExtensions );
    }

    public function menu_image_init() {
        add_post_type_support( 'nav_menu_item', array( 'thumbnail' ) );

        $this->image_sizes = apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_sizes', $this->image_sizes );
        if (is_array($this->image_sizes)) {
            foreach ($this->image_sizes as $name => $params) {
                add_image_size($name, $params[0], $params[1], ( array_key_exists(2, $params) ? $params[2] : false ) );
            }
        }
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'menu-image', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
    }

    public function menu_image_nav_menu_manage_columns( $columns ) {
        return $columns + array( 'image' => __( 'Image', 'menu-image' ) );
    }

    public function menu_image_save_post_action( $post_id, $post ) {
        $menu_image_settings = array(
            'menu_item_image_size',
            'menu_item_image_title_position'
        );
        foreach ( $menu_image_settings as $setting_name ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $setting_name ][ $post_id ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ $setting_name ][ $post_id ] ) ) {
                if ( $post->{"_$setting_name"} != $_POST[ $setting_name ][ $post_id ] ) {
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, "_$setting_name", esc_sql( $_POST[ $setting_name ][ $post_id ] ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function wp_update_nav_menu_item_action( $item_menu_id, $menu_item_db_id ) {
        global $sitepress, $icl_menus_sync;
        if ( class_exists( 'SitePress' ) && $sitepress instanceof SitePress && class_exists( 'ICLMenusSync' ) && $icl_menus_sync instanceof ICLMenusSync ) {
            static $run_times = array();
            $menu_image_settings = array(
                'menu_item_image_size',
                'menu_item_image_title_position',
                'thumbnail_id',
                'thumbnail_hover_id',
            );

            foreach ( $icl_menus_sync->menus as $menu_id => $menu_data ) {
                if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'sync' ][ 'add' ][ $menu_id ] ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $cache_key   = md5( serialize( array( $item_menu_id, 'tax_nav_menu' ) ) );
                $cache_group = 'get_language_for_element';
                wp_cache_delete( $cache_key, $cache_group );
                $lang = $sitepress->get_language_for_element( $item_menu_id, 'tax_nav_menu' );

                if ( !isset( $run_times[ $menu_id ][ $lang ] ) ) {
                    $run_times[ $menu_id ][ $lang ] = 0;
                }

            
                $post_item_ids = array();
                foreach ( $_POST[ 'sync' ][ 'add' ][ $menu_id ] as $id => $lang_array ) {
                    if ( array_key_exists( $lang, $lang_array ) ) {
                        $post_item_ids[ ] = $id;
                    }
                }
                if ( !array_key_exists( $run_times[ $menu_id ][ $lang ], $post_item_ids ) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $orig_item_id = $post_item_ids[ $run_times[ $menu_id ][ $lang ] ];

                $orig_item_meta = get_metadata( 'post', $orig_item_id );
                foreach ( $menu_image_settings as $meta ) {
                    if ( isset( $orig_item_meta[ "_$meta" ] ) && isset( $orig_item_meta[ "_$meta" ][ 0 ] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, "_$meta", $orig_item_meta[ "_$meta" ][ 0 ] );
                    }
                }
                $run_times[ $menu_id ][ $lang ] ++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function menu_image_edit_nav_menu_walker_filter() {
        return 'Menu_Image_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit';
    }

    public function menu_image_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $item ) {
        if ( !isset( $item->thumbnail_id ) ) {
            $item->thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $item->ID );
        }
        if ( !isset( $item->thumbnail_hover_id ) ) {
            $item->thumbnail_hover_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_thumbnail_hover_id', true );
        }
        if ( !isset( $item->image_size ) ) {
            $item->image_size = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_image_size', true );
        }
        if ( !isset( $item->title_position ) ) {
            $item->title_position = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_image_title_position', true );
        }

        return $item;
    }

    public function menu_image_nav_menu_link_attributes_filter( $atts, $item, $args, $depth = null ) {
        $this->setProcessed( $item->ID );
        $position = $item->title_position ? $item->title_position : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_title_position', 'after' );
        $class    = ! empty( $atts[ 'class' ] ) ? $atts[ 'class' ] : '';
        $class    .= " menu-image-title-{$position}";
        if ( $item->thumbnail_hover_id ) {
            $class .= ' menu-image-hovered';
        } elseif ( $item->thumbnail_id ) {
            $class .= ' menu-image-not-hovered';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $args->walker ) && class_exists( 'FlatsomeNavDropdown' ) && $args->walker instanceof FlatsomeNavDropdown && ! is_null( $depth ) && $depth === 0 ) {
            $class .= ' nav-top-link';
        }
        $atts[ 'class' ] = trim( $class );

        return $atts;
    }

    public function menu_image_nav_menu_item_title_filter( $title, $item, $depth = null, $args = null) {
        if (is_numeric($item)) {
            $item = wp_setup_nav_menu_item( get_post( $item ) );
        }
        $image_size = $item->image_size ? $item->image_size : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_size', 'menu-36x36' );
        $position   = $item->title_position ? $item->title_position : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_title_position', 'after' );
        $class      = "menu-image-title-{$position}";
        $this->setUsedAttachments( $image_size, $item->thumbnail_id );
        $image = '';
        if ( $item->thumbnail_hover_id ) {
            $this->setUsedAttachments( $image_size, $item->thumbnail_hover_id );
            $hover_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $item->thumbnail_hover_id, $image_size );
            $margin_size     = $hover_image_src[ 1 ];
            $image           = "<span class='menu-image-hover-wrapper'>";
            $image .= wp_get_attachment_image( $item->thumbnail_id, $image_size, false, "class=menu-image {$class}" );
            $image .= wp_get_attachment_image(
                $item->thumbnail_hover_id, $image_size, false, array(
                    'class' => "hovered-image {$class}",
                    'style' => "margin-left: -{$margin_size}px;",
                )
            );
            $image .= '</span>';;
        } elseif ( $item->thumbnail_id ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $item->thumbnail_id, $image_size, false, "class=menu-image {$class}" );
        }
        $none = ''; // Sugar.
        switch ( $position ) {
            case 'hide':
            case 'before':
            case 'above':
                $item_args = array( $none, $title, $image );
                break;
            case 'after':
            default:
                $item_args = array( $image, $title, $none );
                break;
        }
        $title = vsprintf( '%s<span class="menu-image-title">%s</span>%s', $item_args );

        return $title;
    }

    public function menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        if ( $this->isProcessed( $item->ID ) ) {
            return $item_output;
        }
        $attributes = !empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes_array = shortcode_parse_atts($attributes);

        $image_size = $item->image_size ? $item->image_size : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_size', 'menu-36x36' );
        $position   = $item->title_position ? $item->title_position : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_title_position', 'after' );
        $class      = "menu-image-title-{$position}";
        $this->setUsedAttachments( $image_size, $item->thumbnail_id );
        $image = '';
        if ( $item->thumbnail_hover_id ) {
            $this->setUsedAttachments( $image_size, $item->thumbnail_hover_id );
            $hover_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $item->thumbnail_hover_id, $image_size );
            $margin_size     = $hover_image_src[ 1 ];
            $image           = "<span class='menu-image-hover-wrapper'>";
            $image .= wp_get_attachment_image( $item->thumbnail_id, $image_size, false, "class=menu-image {$class}" );
            $image .= wp_get_attachment_image(
                $item->thumbnail_hover_id, $image_size, false, array(
                    'class' => "hovered-image {$class}",
                    'style' => "margin-left: -{$margin_size}px;",
                )
            );
            $image .= '</span>';;
            $class .= ' menu-image-hovered';
        } elseif ( $item->thumbnail_id ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $item->thumbnail_id, $image_size, false, "class=menu-image {$class}" );
            $class .= ' menu-image-not-hovered';
        }
        $attributes_array['class'] = $class;

        $attributes_array = apply_filters( 'menu_image_link_attributes', $attributes_array, $item, $depth, $args );
        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $attributes_array as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
            $attributes .= "{$attr_name}=\"$attr_value\" ";
        }
        $attributes = trim($attributes);

        $item_output = "{$args->before}<a {$attributes}>";
        $link        = $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $none        = ''; 
        switch ( $position ) {
            case 'hide':
            case 'before':
            case 'above':
                $item_args = array( $none, $link, $image );
                break;
            case 'after':
            default:
                $item_args = array( $image, $link, $none );
                break;
        }
        $item_output .= vsprintf( '%s<span class="menu-image-title">%s</span>%s', $item_args );
        $item_output .= "</a>{$args->after}";

        return $item_output;
    }

    public function menu_image_add_inline_style_action() {
        wp_register_style( 'menu-image', SF()->plugin_url() . '/assets/css/menu-image.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'menu-image' );
    }

    public function menu_image_admin_head_nav_menus_action() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-image-admin', SF()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/menu-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script(
            'menu-image-admin', 'menuImage', array(
                  'l10n'               => array(
                    'uploaderTitle'      => __( 'Chose menu image', 'menu-image' ),
                    'uploaderButtonText' => __( 'Select', 'menu-image' ),
                ),
                'settings' => array(
                    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'update-menu-item' ),
                ),
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_enqueue_style( 'editor-buttons' );
    }

    public function menu_image_delete_menu_item_image_action() {

        $menu_item_id = (int) $_REQUEST[ 'menu-item' ];

        check_admin_referer( 'delete-menu_item_image_' . $menu_item_id );

        if ( is_nav_menu_item( $menu_item_id ) && has_post_thumbnail( $menu_item_id ) ) {
            delete_post_thumbnail( $menu_item_id );
            delete_post_meta( $menu_item_id, '_thumbnail_hover_id' );
            delete_post_meta( $menu_item_id, '_menu_item_image_size' );
            delete_post_meta( $menu_item_id, '_menu_item_image_title_position' );
        }
    }

    public function wp_post_thumbnail_only_html( $item_id ) {
        $default_size = apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_size', 'menu-36x36' );
        $markup       = '<p class="description description-thin" ><label>%s<br /><a title="%s" href="#" class="set-post-thumbnail button%s" data-item-id="%s" style="height: auto;">%s</a>%s</label></p>';

        $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $item_id );
        $content      = sprintf(
            $markup,
            esc_html__( 'Menu image', 'menu-image' ),
            $thumbnail_id ? esc_attr__( 'Change menu item image', 'menu-image' ) : esc_attr__( 'Set menu item image', 'menu-image' ),
            '',
            $item_id,
            $thumbnail_id ? wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, $default_size ) : esc_html__( 'Set image', 'menu-image' ),
            $thumbnail_id ? '<a href="#" class="remove-post-thumbnail">' . __( 'Remove', 'menu-image' ) . '</a>' : ''
        );
        return $content;
    }

    public function wp_post_thumbnail_html( $item_id ) {
        $default_size = apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_size', 'menu-36x36' );
        $content      = $this->wp_post_thumbnail_only_html( $item_id );

        $image_size = get_post_meta( $item_id, '_menu_item_image_size', true );
        if ( !$image_size ) {
            $image_size = $default_size;
        }
        $title_position = get_post_meta( $item_id, '_menu_item_image_title_position', true );
        if ( !$title_position ) {
            $title_position = apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_title_position', 'after' );
        }

    

        $content = "<div class='menu-item-images' style='min-height:70px'>$content</div>";
        return apply_filters( 'admin_menu_item_thumbnail_html', $content, $item_id );
    }

    public function wp_ajax_set_menu_item_thumbnail() {
        $json = !empty( $_REQUEST[ 'json' ] );

        $post_ID = intval( $_POST[ 'post_id' ] );
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_ID ) ) {
            wp_die( - 1 );
        }

        $thumbnail_id = intval( $_POST[ 'thumbnail_id' ] );
        $is_hovered   = (bool) $_POST[ 'is_hover' ];

        check_ajax_referer( "update-menu-item" );

        if ( $thumbnail_id == '-1' ) {
            if ( $is_hovered ) {
                $success = delete_post_meta( $post_ID, '_thumbnail_hover_id' );
            } else {
                $success = delete_post_thumbnail( $post_ID );
            }
        } else {
            if ( $is_hovered ) {
                $success = update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_thumbnail_hover_id', $thumbnail_id );
            } else {
                $success = set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $thumbnail_id );
            }
        }

        if ( $success ) {
            $return = $this->wp_post_thumbnail_only_html( $post_ID );
            $json ? wp_send_json_success( $return ) : wp_die( $return );
        }

        wp_die( 0 );
    }

    public function menu_item_custom_fields( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args ){

        ?>
        <div class="field-image hide-if-no-js wp-media-buttons">
            <?php echo $this->wp_post_thumbnail_html( $item_id ) ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }


    public function jetpack_photon_override_image_downsize_filter( $prevent, $data ) {
        return $this->isAttachmentUsed( $data[ 'attachment_id' ], $data[ 'size' ] );
    }


    public function setUsedAttachments( $size, $id ) {
        $this->used_attachments[ $size ][ ] = $id;
    }

    
    public function isAttachmentUsed( $id, $size = null ) {
        if ( ! is_null( $size ) ) {
            return is_string( $size ) && isset( $this->used_attachments[ $size ] ) && in_array( $id, $this->used_attachments[ $size ] );
        } else {
            foreach ( $this->used_attachments as $used_attachment ) {
                if ( in_array( $id, $used_attachment ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    
    public function wp_get_attachment_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
        if ( $this->isAttachmentUsed( $attachment->ID, $size ) ) {
            unset( $attr['sizes'], $attr['srcset'] );
        }

        return $attr;
    }


    protected function setProcessed( $id ) {
        $this->processed[] = $id;
    }


    protected function isProcessed( $id ) {
        return in_array( $id, $this->processed );
    }
}

$menu_image = new SNAP_Menu_Image();

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php');

class Menu_Image_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit extends Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit {

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;
        $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth = $depth > $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth ? $depth : $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;

        ob_start();
        $item_id = esc_attr( $item->ID );
        $removed_args = array(
            'action',
            'customlink-tab',
            'edit-menu-item',
            'menu-item',
            'page-tab',
            '_wpnonce',
        );

        $original_title = false;
        if ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) {
            $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $item->object_id, $item->object, 'raw' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $original_title ) )
                $original_title = false;
        } elseif ( 'post_type' == $item->type ) {
            $original_object = get_post( $item->object_id );
            $original_title = get_the_title( $original_object->ID );
        } elseif ( 'post_type_archive' == $item->type ) {
            $original_object = get_post_type_object( $item->object );
            if ( $original_object ) {
                $original_title = $original_object->labels->archives;
            }
        }

        $classes = array(
            'menu-item menu-item-depth-' . $depth,
            'menu-item-' . esc_attr( $item->object ),
            'menu-item-edit-' . ( ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? 'active' : 'inactive'),
        );

        $title = $item->title;

        if ( ! empty( $item->_invalid ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-invalid';
            $title = sprintf( __( '%s (Invalid)' ), $item->title );
        } elseif ( isset( $item->post_status ) && 'draft' == $item->post_status ) {
            $classes[] = 'pending';
            $title = sprintf( __('%s (Pending)'), $item->title );
        }

        $title = ( ! isset( $item->label ) || '' == $item->label ) ? $title : $item->label;

        $submenu_text = '';
        if ( 0 == $depth )
            $submenu_text = 'style="display: none;"';

        ?>
        <li id="menu-item-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $classes ); ?>">
            <div class="menu-item-bar">
                <div class="menu-item-handle">
                    <span class="item-title"><span class="menu-item-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span> <span class="is-submenu" <?php echo $submenu_text; ?>><?php _e( 'sub item' ); ?></span></span>
                    <span class="item-controls">
                        <span class="item-type"><?php echo esc_html( $item->type_label ); ?></span>
                        <span class="item-order hide-if-js">
                            <a href="<?php
                                echo wp_nonce_url(
                                    add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                            'action' => 'move-up-menu-item',
                                            'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                        ),
                                        remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                                    ),
                                    'move-menu_item'
                                );
                            ?>" class="item-move-up" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Move up' ) ?>">&#8593;</a>
                            |
                            <a href="<?php
                                echo wp_nonce_url(
                                    add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                            'action' => 'move-down-menu-item',
                                            'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                        ),
                                        remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) )
                                    ),
                                    'move-menu_item'
                                );
                            ?>" class="item-move-down" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Move down' ) ?>">&#8595;</a>
                        </span>
                        <a class="item-edit" id="edit-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="<?php
                            echo ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) : add_query_arg( 'edit-menu-item', $item_id, remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php#menu-item-settings-' . $item_id ) ) );
                        ?>" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Edit menu item' ); ?>"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Edit' ); ?></span></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-item-settings wp-clearfix" id="menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                <?php if ( 'custom' == $item->type ) : ?>
                    <p class="field-url description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'URL' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-url" name="menu-item-url[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->url ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            
            
                <p class="field-xfn description description-thin">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Link Relationship (XFN)' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-xfn" name="menu-item-xfn[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->xfn ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>

                <?php
                do_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', $item_id, $item, $depth, $args );
                ?>

                
                <fieldset class="field-move hide-if-no-js description description-wide">
                    <span class="field-move-visual-label" aria-hidden="true"><?php _e( 'Move' ); ?></span>
                    <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-up" data-dir="up"><?php _e( 'Up one' ); ?></button>
                    <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-down" data-dir="down"><?php _e( 'Down one' ); ?></button>
                    <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-left" data-dir="left"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-right" data-dir="right"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="button-link menus-move menus-move-top" data-dir="top"><?php _e( 'To the top' ); ?></button>
                </fieldset>

                <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
                    <?php if ( 'custom' != $item->type && $original_title !== false ) : ?>
                        <p class="link-to-original">
                            <?php printf( __('Original: %s'), '<a href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '">' . esc_html( $original_title ) . '</a>' ); ?>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <a class="item-delete submitdelete deletion" id="delete-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="<?php
                    echo wp_nonce_url(
                        add_query_arg(
                            array(
                                'action' => 'delete-menu-item',
                                'menu-item' => $item_id,
                            ),
                            admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' )
                        ),
                        'delete-menu_item_' . $item_id
                    ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Remove' ); ?></a> <span class="meta-sep hide-if-no-js"> | </span> <a class="item-cancel submitcancel hide-if-no-js" id="cancel-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'edit-menu-item' => $item_id, 'cancel' => time() ), admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) );
                        ?>#menu-item-settings-<?php echo $item_id; ?>"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></a>
                </div>

                <input class="menu-item-data-db-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-db-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-object-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object_id ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-object" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-parent-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-parent-id[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_item_parent ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-position" type="hidden" name="menu-item-position[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_order ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-type" type="hidden" name="menu-item-type[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->type ); ?>" />
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-item-transport"></ul>
        <?php
        $output .= ob_get_clean();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide all of the code? what you have put here is partial of it

Comment: It's a lot of code, but I updated the question anyway...thanks

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the generated HTML? Also, are you certain this is a PHP problem and not a JavaScript problem? What have you done to debug this so far? Can you confirm how many times `wp_post_thumbnail_html` is called and what the parameter's value (`$item_id`)is each time?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones
all the code has been matched, does nothing, and the button is being called in the code a `<? php echo $this->wp_post_thumbnail_html($content);?>` in js I only make calls to functionality, unless it's because of html without Ajax

Comment: From the looks of it, this function is outputting something like `<p>image<br><a><img /></a></p>`. But your example also includes the word `Menu` above this, which doesn't appear to be in your PHP code here. So is it possible that `<? php echo $this->wp_post_thumbnail_html($content);?>` is being called twice from your template? Please include the relevant template code that is calling this function.

Comment: the structure is being assembled in `public function wp_post_thumbnail_only_html` and I updated the image to see the buttons

Comment: You're missing my point - can you edit your question to include both the generated HTML of the fields in your screenshot, as well as the template code that is calling this function? From the looks of it, your function might be working as expected, but if the template is calling it twice then _that's_ where the issue would be - not in `wp_post_thumbnail_html`.

Comment: the entire hmtl is at the end in the code, there is no more html

Answer (score 0):

As basic as the answer is, I'll leave the question active...

I had instantiated the class 2 times!